# Library to make HTML XHTML-compliant

Tags: .net, html, tidy

What libraries can you advise except HtmlAgilityPack and Tidy?

To be able to apply XPath queries to HTML content, I use either Tidy as console program with some tricks to get C# XmlDocument or Html Agility Pack. Both these libs are outdated - HAP wasn't changed since May-2010 and Tidy since 2008. I had bad experience using HAP because it did not fix document structure by closing tags even after applying next trick:

```
public static HtmlDocument MakeEmptyDocument()
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
    doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
    doc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
    doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
    return doc;
}

public static HtmlDocument LoadHtmlDocumentFromString(string content)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = MakeEmptyDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(content);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        doc.Save(sw);

    using (StringReader sw = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
        doc.Load(sw);
    return doc;
}
```

Generally I preferred Tidy but now I have a case when it breaks quite simple document completely and removes BIG content part from it.
So it looks like we need alternatives that can be used from .NET .

Answer (score 0):

The Tidy project has been taken over by the HTACG (HTML Tidy Advocacy Community Group) and now has released tidy5 (as of late 2015) with libtidy libraries which provide a C interface which "may be called from a great number of programming languages".  See the following:

[HTML Tidy Project (Developers Section)](http://www.html-tidy.org/developer/)